# Sniff traffic with wireshark in wireless network

Tags: ios, networking, wireshark

I'm debugging the iOS application server, and it looks like client app doesn't send proper data. I do have an iOS device to run the app, but I don't have a mac to run it in emulator or with debugger connected. So I've decided to inspect the network traffic first.

In my set-up I have a Wi-Fi router which serves internet for my Windows Notebook and my iOS device. And I have a remote server running the server application. Server has a domain and application uses a domain.

My first idea was to sniff all the trafic to and from specific host with wireshark from my notebook. But Wireshark doesn't seem to be able to capture any packets between my phone and application server. I've tried sniffing on wireless interface with "host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" setting, where XXX.. - is the IP of application server.

The next step will be running the server app locally and changing the local DNS settings so the phone will connect to local instance, not remote. But I'd like to try the sniffing first. Is possible in such setup? What should I change in Wireshark setting to actually see the traffic?

Comment: Well at first be aware that you need wireless card in your notebook that support promiscuous mode. Otherwise you will be not able to capture that traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using standard HTTP for your communication Charles Proxy is pretty much the standard for inspecting traffic from mobile devices to servers. You run Charles on your computer and point your phone to use your computer as a proxy server on port 8888 (the default) and you should be good to go.

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

If you are using your own packet protocol you should and need to use WireShark to inspect traffic see this part of the documentation about OSX setup.

http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Mac_OS_X